# Is it possible to reintegrate a SVN feature branch into a different release branch?

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging, svn-merge, svn-merge-reintegrate

Let's say I have created a SVN feature branch "Feature123" from a release branch "Version1.0", to work on a new feature. I've made some changes in my feature branch and committed them to the repository, but not yet reintegrated the feature branch into the release branch.  In the meantime, we also have created a "Version2.0" release branch, for a future release.  Now my manager tells me that he doesn't want my feature123 in version 1.0, but in version 2.0 instead.

Is there a way that I can reintegrate my Feature123 branch into Version2.0, even though the feature branch was created as a branch of Version1.0?

Comment: Not an answer exactly, but these cases show advantages of branch schemes with trunk - reintegrate features there and choose in which release they should go.

Comment: But how do you then extract just distinct features from the trunk for inclusion in a certain release?  Once back in the trunk, a feature would be merged in with changes from other features.

Comment: In my work every feature has 1 commit in trunk (usually it's a merge). If release branch was made before this feature implementation, changes are simply merged to that release branch. This works conveniently with two assumptions: (1) there are no _many_ such features (2) mostly features do not change most of application code.

Answer (score 0):

You can in Subversion merge **from any** path to **any path** - all branches are equal by nature (and your branches have common parent anyway)